# Currentless voltage difference in MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

How does a MOSFET have a voltage difference on the gate without current running through?

Comment: How does a battery have voltage between it's poles without current?

Comment: There's literally a piece of glass (silicon dioxide) between the gate and the rest of the MOSFET.

Comment: There should be zero voltage difference on the gate at all times.

Comment: Your wording is poor, are you asking: "How can a MOSFET remain in a conductive (or non-conductive if you prefer) state while there is no current flowing into the gate?"

Comment: `a voltage difference` between the gate and what?

Answer (score 5):

> How does a MOSFET has a voltage diffrance on the GATE without current running through????

Much the same way as a capacitor does. Current flows initially, to charge it up. No current has to flow to maintain the voltage, like would be the case with a resistor. When you want the voltage on the gate to go down again, you have to pull current out of it to discharge it.

This leads to the very different behaviour of a FET used for switching a load on and off from time to time, and one used to switch current at tens or hundreds of kHz. For occasional switching, you can get away with a low power logic gate, or very high value resistor, to bias the gate. The FET will take some time to switch, and absorb a pulse of power due to the load current times its intermediate VDS, but as a one-off event, it's not a problem. When required to switch at hundreds of kHz, a 'gate driver' IC is commonly employed, which is specified to source and sink several amps into and out of the gate to charge/discharge its considerable input capacitance quickly, to reduce the length of that pulse of power.